# Why mesos-slave asked to kill a task for more than 2 hours on a reboot slave?

Tags: mesos, marathon

Why mesos-slave asked to kill a task for more than 2 hours on a reboot slave?

I'm running a mesos cluster with three masters and four slaves currently on the cloud environment.

- Mesos Version: 0.28.
- Marathon Version: 0.15.2

I found in case, if I reboot a slave which there are docker tasks running. After rebooting, the task will be in staging state on that slave for more then 2 hours. After 2 houes later, the Marathon can launch the task on other "slave.

If check the log, I could see it stuck with "Asked to kill task" and "Ignoring kill task" for about 2 hours.

Does anyone knows why the Mesos need trying to kill the dead task for more than 2 hours?

Log after reboot:

---

```
May 11 10:12:18 euca-10-254-234-236 mesos-slave[824]: I0511 10:12:18.199795   964 slave.cpp:1891] Asked to kill task project-hub_project-hub-backend.e764cc0d-173f-11e6-b66e-d00dacb0c46b of framework 17cd3756-1d59-4dfc-984d-3fe09f6b5730-0000
May 11 10:12:18 euca-10-254-234-236 mesos-slave[824]: W0511 10:12:18.199831   964 slave.cpp:2018] Ignoring kill task project-hub_project-hub-backend.e764cc0d-173f-11e6-b66e-d00dacb0c46b because the executor 'project-hub_project-hub-backend.e764cc0d-173f-11e6-b66e-d00dacb0c46b' of framework 17cd3756-1d59-4dfc-984d-3fe09f6b5730-0000 is terminating/terminated
May 11 10:12:18 euca-10-254-234-236 mesos-slave[824]: I0511 10:12:18.199872   964 slave.cpp:1891] Asked to kill task docker-registry.d1c20255-173f-11e6-b66e-d00dacb0c46b of framework 17cd3756-1d59-4dfc-984d-3fe09f6b5730-0000
```

log after 2 hours later:

---

```
I0511 12:15:48.200348   963 slave.cpp:1891] Asked to kill task project-hub_project-hub-backend.e764cc0d-173f-11e6-b66e-d00dacb0c46b of framework 17cd3756-1d59-4dfc-984d-3fe09f6b5730-0000
W0511 12:15:48.200409   963 slave.cpp:2018] Ignoring kill task project-hub_project-hub-backend.e764cc0d-173f-11e6-b66e-d00dacb0c46b because the executor 'project-hub_project-hub-backend.e764cc0d-173f-11e6-b66e-d00dacb0c46b' of framework 17cd3756-1d59-4dfc-984d-3fe09f6b5730-0000 is terminating/terminated
I0511 12:15:48.200429   963 slave.cpp:1891] Asked to kill task docker-registry.d1c20255-173f-11e6-b66e-d00dacb0c46b of framework 17cd3756-1d59-4dfc-984d-3fe09f6b5730-0000
W0511 12:15:48.200438   963 slave.cpp:2018] Ignoring kill task docker-registry.d1c20255-173f-11e6-b66e-d00dacb0c46b because the executor 'docker-registry.d1c20255-173f-11e6-b66e-d00dacb0c46b' of framework 17cd3756-1d59-4dfc-984d-3fe09f6b5730-0000 is terminating/terminated
I0511 12:15:51.485391   964 http.cpp:190] HTTP GET for /slave(1)/state from 10.145.150.124:59955 with User-Agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36'
I0511 12:15:51.509351   965 http.cpp:190] HTTP GET for /slave(1)/state from 10.145.150.124:59955 with User-Agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36'
W0511 12:15:51.656379   960 slave.cpp:4979] Failed to get resource statistics for executor 'project-hub_project-hub-backend.e764cc0d-173f-11e6-b66e-d00dacb0c46b' of framework 17cd3756-1d59-4dfc-984d-3fe09f6b5730-0000: Unknown container: b2f5b385-444b-4174-9a1c-8ccd2d3184dc
W0511 12:15:51.656409   960 slave.cpp:4979] Failed to get resource statistics for executor 'docker-registry.d1c20255-173f-11e6-b66e-d00dacb0c46b' of framework 17cd3756-1d59-4dfc-984d-3fe09f6b5730-0000: Unknown container: 1ab25a1b-79fe-430b-9751-330586a1fbef
I0511 12:15:51.663321   965 http.cpp:190] HTTP GET for /slave(1)/state from 10.145.150.124:59560 with User-Agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36'
I0511 12:15:51.671294   965 http.cpp:190] HTTP GET for /slave(1)/state from 10.145.150.124:59560 with User-Agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36'
W0511 12:15:52.156903   962 slave.cpp:4979] Failed to get resource statistics for executor 'project-hub_project-hub-backend.e764cc0d-173f-11e6-b66e-d00dacb0c46b' of framework 17cd3756-1d59-4dfc-984d-3fe09f6b5730-0000: Unknown container: b2f5b385-444b-4174-9a1c-8ccd2d3184dc
W0511 12:15:52.156941   962 slave.cpp:4979] Failed to get resource statistics for executor 'docker-registry.d1c20255-173f-11e6-b66e-d00dacb0c46b' of framework 17cd3756-1d59-4dfc-984d-3fe09f6b5730-0000: Unknown container: 1ab25a1b-79fe-430b-9751-330586a1fbef
E0511 12:15:52.247448   962 slave.cpp:3773] Container '1ab25a1b-79fe-430b-9751-330586a1fbef' for executor 'docker-registry.d1c20255-173f-11e6-b66e-d00dacb0c46b' of framework 17cd3756-1d59-4dfc-984d-3fe09f6b5730-0000 failed to start:  future discarded
E0511 12:15:52.247612   962 slave.cpp:3773] Container 'b2f5b385-444b-4174-9a1c-8ccd2d3184dc' for executor 'project-hub_project-hub-backend.e764cc0d-173f-11e6-b66e-d00dacb0c46b' of framework 17cd3756-1d59-4dfc-984d-3fe09f6b5730-0000 failed to start:  future discarded
W0511 12:15:52.247642   962 composing.cpp:541] Container '1ab25a1b-79fe-430b-9751-330586a1fbef' is already destroyed
W0511 12:15:52.247660   962 composing.cpp:541] Container 'b2f5b385-444b-4174-9a1c-8ccd2d3184dc' is already destroyed
E0511 12:15:52.247704   962 slave.cpp:3870] Termination of executor 'docker-registry.d1c20255-173f-11e6-b66e-d00dacb0c46b' of framework 17cd3756-1d59-4dfc-984d-3fe09f6b5730-0000 failed: Unknown container: 1ab25a1b-79fe-430b-9751-330586a1fbef
I0511 12:15:52.248374   962 slave.cpp:3002] Handling status update TASK_FAILED (UUID: b399e8ce-832c-4b06-a15f-3c155536b872) for task docker-registry.d1c20255-173f-11e6-b66e-d00dacb0c46b of framework 17cd3756-1d59-4dfc-984d-3fe09f6b5730-0000 from @0.0.0.0:0
E0511 12:15:52.248458   962 slave.cpp:3870] Termination of executor 'project-hub_project-hub-backend.e764cc0d-173f-11e6-b66e-d00dacb0c46b' of framework 17cd3756-1d59-4dfc-984d-3fe09f6b5730-0000 failed: Unknown container: b2f5b385-444b-4174-9a1c-8ccd2d3184dc
```

Comment: Are you setting the agent flag `executor_shutdown_grace_period` if so, at which value?

Comment: You also see there was an original `KILL_TASK` message issued, which sets the `TASK` in a `TERMINATING` state and ask the executor to kill the task. If the executor ignores the message you end up in that situation. Could you post logs of the first time the task is attempted to be killed?